# How can I detect JavaFx double click on listView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, double-click

I just finished writing a code that open an element after clicking on it on the listView.
But I wish to add a feature that allows user to modify that element, so  user double clicks on the element to modify and simple clicks it to show his pannel . 
Any solution for that ? 
Thank you

Comment: all interaction is handled in the cell: so you need a custom cell which listens to double-clicks and do what you want

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setOnMouseClicked` in a custom `CellFactory`.

```
yourListView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<YourObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(YourObject item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            //do other stuff here
            setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickedEvent -> {
                if (mouseClickedEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && mouseClickedEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("double clicked");                       
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```